# How to threshold value in Python

Tags: python

I have a value that's need to be greater than some threshold. Right now I use it like this:

```py
value = int(input())
threshold = 10

value = threshold if value < threshold else value
```

Are there any better ways to do it? Is it "Pythonic" enough?

Comment: `value = max(value, threshold)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max()` function (and there's `min()` if your threshold should cap the value)

```
value = max(threshold, value)
```

Comment: Your (now deleted) answer has no votes.